# How can I get job configuration in command line?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I get get running apps with this `yarn application -appStates RUNNING` then I get one **applicationID** from list.

then I can get **status** of app with this: `yarn application -status`

I want to get **job configuration information** on command line. it is possible?

[image]

Comment: What output are you expecting exactly?

Comment: I want to get confs in there , in browser i can see there are key values like query vs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not "Job Configuration". It is whole cluster config.

You can use `cURL` to parse it

```bash
$ curl -s http://localhost:8088/conf | grep defaultFS
<property><name>fs.defaultFS</name><value>file:///</value><final>false</final><source>core-default.xml</source></property>
<property><name>mapreduce.job.hdfs-servers</name><value>${fs.defaultFS}</value><final>false</final><source>mapred-default.xml</source></property>
```